# "URL reservation delete failed , Error: 87" when I 'netsh http delete'

Tags: windows, networking

I get the following error when delete a rule:

```
C:> netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:80

URL reservation delete failed , Error: 87
The parameter is incorrect.
```

When I do 'netsh http show urlacl', I see this rule:

```
  Reserved URL            : http://localhost:80/
      User: myself
          Listen: Yes
          Delegate: No
          SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-21-124525095-708259637-1543119021-1467807)
```

What is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're missing a trailing slash. Instead use:

```
netsh http delete urlacl url=http://localhost:80/
```

When you use `netsh show urlacl` on the same URL, the Reserved URL entry has a trailing slash. This is the URL you should be using for any urlacl operations.